# invoke and wait which interacts with a sub class

Tags: java, swing, try-catch, invokelater, invokeandwait

I have found many fine examples of invoke later and invoke and wait across the site.
However the issue that I have is that the I would like to get a response from a class which is called by the main method

Could any one provide some code that a main method calls a sub method to see how this is constructed with an invoe and wait method?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

[SwingUtilities#invokeAndWait or invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29) take a `Runnable` as an argument so you can not get a result back.
Look into [SwingWorkers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) where you can do an action in a background thread and get back the result to update the UI inside the EDT